# Creating an `std::forward` alias - unexpected results

Tags: c++, templates, auto, c++14, perfect-forwarding

I created an `std::forward` alias that should behave exactly as `std::forward`.

```
template<class T> 
constexpr decltype(auto) fwd(T mValue) noexcept
{ 
    return std::forward<T>(mValue); 
}
```

I then replaced all occurrences of `std::forward<...>` with `fwd<...>` in my codebase.

Compiled all the projects with `g++ 4.9` - all tests passed, everything worked properly.

Then I tried compiling with `clang++ 3.5`. Some tests seemed to randomly fail, and the reason was `fwd<...>`. Replacing it with `std::forward<...>` again fixed the failing tests.

I tried writing `fwd<...>` with the trailing return type syntax, as I thought `decltype(auto)` wasn't working:

```
template<class T> 
constexpr auto fwd(T mValue) noexcept -> decltype(std::forward<T>(mValue)) 
{ 
    return std::forward<T>(mValue); 
}
```

Same results: `g++` works, `clang++` doesn't.

I then looked up the signature of `std::forward` on cppreference, and implemented my alias like this:

```
template<class T> 
constexpr T&& fwd(std::remove_reference_t<T>& t) { return std::forward<T>(t); }

template<class T> 
constexpr T&& fwd(std::remove_reference_t<T>&& t) { return std::forward<T>(t); }
```

This works (all tests pass) both on `g++` and `clang++`.

**Why isn't the `decltype(auto)` version working? Shouldn't it return the exact same return type as `std::forward`?**

Comment: Your alias forces copies for rvalues, instead of moves.

Comment: have you tried to use use `auto` or `decltype(auto)` in the last two working implementations while maintaining `std::remove_reference_t` in the arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to declare mValue as a move reference

```
template <typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) fwd(std::remove_reference_t<T> &&mValue)
{
    return std::forward<T>(mValue);
}
template <typename T>
constexpr decltype(auto) fwd(std::remove_reference_t<T> &mValue)
{
    return std::forward<T>(mValue);
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure if `fwd(T &&mValue)` will work if `T` is `Type &` or `Type &&`

Comment: Note that the version with l-value reference is also needed else you got a compilation error : (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3505f7b8b37980e2)